# Javascript | Location of X and Y clicked on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the position of an x and y location that is clicked when on a image. The reason is because I want to be able to add a spot to this image which will display some information about where it is. The spot will be dynamically loaded from a SQL database, but that isn't the concern at the minute.

I've had a look on Stack and I've seen a few questions where it says to use `e.pageX - element.offsetLeft` for the x location and `e.pageY - element.offsetTop` however placing a div on the page with a style equal to the coordinates for example `<div style="position: absolute; top: 253px; left: 50px;></div>` it doesn't appear anywhere near where I want it too. Left being the x and top being the y

So in a summary this is what I am trying to achieve:

- Light box appears in the middle of the screen with the selected image on.
- When clicking on the image, the x and y get calculated and I can then use these to position a element via css to be exactly where they clicked on the image.

```js
var $imgCont = $('#img-wrap'),
    $img = $('#img')

$img.click(function(e) {
  var pos = {
    left: e.pageX - $img.offset().left,
    top: e.pageY - $img.offset().top
  }
  $('<div class="box">').css(pos).appendTo($imgCont)

})
```

```css
#img-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click image to add boxes</p>
<div id="img-wrap">
  <img id='img' src=http://via.placeholder.com/400x400 ">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with what you have tried yet?

Comment: Absolute positioned element's are based off the position of the first positioned parent (relative,absolute,fixed). Are both in the same positioned parent?

Comment: Depends where you append the new div and it's closest positioned ancestor. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's weird because I've just done code which is relatively the same but different in the jsfiddle and it seems to be working on their... I'm doing it into a parent div with the styles `height: 100%; width: 100%`

Comment: @PatrickEvans The parent has a position of fixed on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the image is wrapped in a container with position and append to that same container

```js
var $imgCont = $('#img-wrap'),
    $img = $('#img')

$img.click(function(e) {
  var pos = {
    left: e.pageX - $img.offset().left,
    top: e.pageY - $img.offset().top
  }
  $('<div class="box">').css(pos).appendTo($imgCont)

})
```

```css
#img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px 0 0 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 400px
}

.box {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click image to add boxes</p>
<div id="img-wrap">
  <img id='img' src=http://via.placeholder.com/400x400 ">
</div>
```

Comment: What if the outer div `#img-wrap` had the style `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,.9); top: 0; left: 0;` I'm trying to achieve it so the image looks as though it is highlighted. However, it seems as though them styles are causing the issue

Comment: As in an overlay that obscures image but box is clear?

Comment: as in, the background is dark but the image is clear. Question though, would flex have an effect on this? I copied your fiddle over with my styles and flex is throwing it off now but I need `justify-content: center; align-items: center`

Comment: flex shouldn't matter when using absolute positioning. Not 100% clear what desired effect is though

Comment: if you have a look at that fiddle, using the same code but using flex, you can see that the boxes position themselves no where near the click. The desired effect is also on that fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/g2khuw5w/

Comment: create a flex demo that reproduces issue. When i click on that demo the top left corner of box ends up right at click point as expected

Comment: i've updated the question, i've added the code into there that reproduces the issue

Comment: Just add an inner div that is positioned https://jsfiddle.net/g2khuw5w/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the offsetY and offsetX of the click event argument

```
<div>
  <p>
    Your image
  </p>
  <div id='container' style="position:relative">
    <img id="myImage" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/120/" />
  </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(myImage).click(
    function(e) {

      var $newContainer = $("<div>You Clicked here</div>");

      $newContainer.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: e.offsetY,
        left: e.offsetX,
        height: '20px',
        'background-color': "red"
      });

      $(container).append($newContainer)
    }
  );
});
```

also see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stefanvdv/acczwxa6/1/)